# Drawing a polygon with circles using java script canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graph, polygon, geometry

Hi all is there a way to draw a polygon with circles using java script canvas, so that I could refer to each circle as an object that contains its coordinates and index inside. I want to draw complete k-partite graphs visually.
Thanks

Comment: please post what u try?

Comment: Yes, preferably your starting code, but at least an illustration with some specifications.

Answer (score 0):

The canvas works a lot like in ms paint. Once you draw a circle on it the computer forgets about the circle and only remembers the pixels. You need to keep track of it yourself:

I haven't tested the code below but hopefully you get the idea.

hopefully this helps you get started:
http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2009/02/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var circles =[];
function addCircle(arg_x,arg_y,arg_rad){
    var newCirc = {};
    newCirc.x = arg_x
    newCirc.y = arg_y
    newCirc.rad = arg_rad
    circles.push(newCirc)
}

function redrawCirc(){
    // loop through circles array and redraw entire graph
    // whenever something changes
    for(var i =0;i<circles.length;i++){
        ctx.arc(circles[i].x,circles[i].y,circles[i].rad,0,Math.PI*2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I know how to draw circles I only need an algorithm that will help me to put those circles polynomially. Imagine there is a 6 partite graph with 4 edges in each part, I want to make this visually look like Hexagon that has 4 edges instead of its vertices.